# Одно значение в функции отсутствует

Tags: python

В функции а есть параметр q, но нет w. Как правильно проверить или переписать код, чтобы если одного аргумента нет - все равно выполнить код? (исключая def a(q,w=6))

```
def a(q,w):
    if w != int():
        w = 6
    print(q,w)

a(q=100)
```

Пока в лучшем случае вышло так - но тоже не верно:

```
def a(q,*args):
    if args:
        print(q,args[0])        
        
    else:
        w = 6
        print(q,w)   

a(q=100)
```

Comment: Откуда ограничение "исключая def a(q,w=6)" ? Это и есть правильный способ.

Comment: Например так: `def a(q, *args)`, а в функции проверять что в `args` и вытаскивать. А к чему такие ограничения? И в чем смысл проверки ` w != int()`? :)

Comment: @nik_golunov, пишите @<ник>, чтобы были уведомления о комментарии. `args` это список, проверять что не пустой можно так: `if args:`

Comment: @nik_golunov, `print(q, args[0])` для не пустого `args`, не пытайтесь просто так вставить код, надеясь, что это сработает :)

Comment: @nik_golunov, при `a(q=100)` выводит `100 6`, при `a(100, 777)` тоже работает. Но тут тогда нужно использовать `**kwargs` вместо `*args`, если хотите именованные параметры использовать, типа: `def a(q, **kwargs):` + `if 'w' in kwargs:` + `print(q, kwargs['w'])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если не указывать значения по умолчанию, тогда можно использовать `kwargs`, в этом случае в функцию нужно передавать именованные аргументы

Пример:

```
def a(q, **kwargs):
    if 'w' in kwargs:
        print(q, kwargs['w'])
    else:
        w = 6
        print(q, w)

a(q=100)
# 100 6

a(100, w=777)
# 100 777

a(q=100, w=777)
# 100 777
```

Comment: @nik_golunov, это имя параметра функции. При `**kwargs` имена параметров будут помещаться в словарь `kwargs`, т.е. можно много параметров передавать, главное, чтобы они были с именами: `a(q=100, w=777, a=1, b=2, c=3)`